# Use a part specification as the argument to a compiled function

Tags: compile, list-manipulation

I have some code that needs to generate a large matrix based on some complicated combinations of smaller matrix elements.  I find that if I write a function for the element of the larger matrix, and then compile that function, I can get the larger matrix much faster.  But I get an error when I compile, and I'd like to find out the right way to do this.

This simpler code reproduces the effect.

```
matrix = RandomReal[{1, 2}, {25, 25}];
tupleslist = RandomInteger[{1, 25}, {1000000, 2}];

matsubtractA[i_Integer, j_Integer] := matrix[[i, j]] - matrix[[j, i]];

Total[matsubtractA @@@ tupleslist] // AbsoluteTiming

matsubtractB = Compile[{{i, _Integer}, {j, _Integer}},
                       matrix[[i, j]] - matrix[[j, i]]
                       ];

Total[matsubtractB @@@ tupleslist] // AbsoluteTiming

matsubtractC = Compile[{{i, _Integer}, {j, _Integer}},
                       Evaluate[
                               matrix[[i, j]] - matrix[[j, i]]
                               ]
                       ];

Total[matsubtractC @@@ tupleslist] // AbsoluteTiming
```

The result is

[image]

All three methods give the same answer, but with much different execution times.  The first attempt at `Compile` is apparently worthless, since it increases the time.  The second attempt, where I use `Evaluate` within compile, greatly improves the execution time but gives a `Part::pkspec1` error when compiling: "The expression i cannot be used as a part specification."

In my actual code, the speedup is even more drastic, so I'll use it even with the error.  But I'd love to know how to fix it.  I even tried using the mysterious third argument to `Compile`,

```
matsubtractC2 = Compile[{{i, _Integer}, {j, _Integer}},
        Evaluate[
            mat = matrix;
            mat[[i, j]] - mat[[j, i]]
            ], 
      {{mat, _Real, 2}}];

Total[matsubtractC @@@ tupleslist] // AbsoluteTiming
```

But I got the same error.

Comment: What happens if you do `With[{mat = matrix}, matsubtract = Compile[{{i, _Integer}, {j, _Integer}}, mat[[i, j]] - mat[[j, i]]]]`?

Comment: @Guesswhoitis., if I do that then it solves it completely.  Post as an answer and I would accept it so you can have the imaginary internet points.  Also, can you explain why this works?

Comment: I'll let somebody (you?) write the answer instead, but let me sketch out what happened there: `With[]` "injected" your huge matrix inside the compiled function, so `Part[]` will no longer have anything to complain about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is more simple: it's the same error you'd get if you tried `matrix[[i, j]]`. You told Mathematica to `Evaluate` the expression `matrix[[i,j]] - matrix[[j,i]]` before doing the `Compile`, so it reduces to that problem. The problem is that the symbol `i` must be an integer to be a valid part specification: `Part[{1, 2, 3}, i]` throws an error.

Of course, Mathematica keeps the expression unevaluated, so you can subsequently substitute `i -> 1` to get the answer `1`. You can prevent the error from being thrown using `Quiet`.

Comment: Why is it significantly faster when I use `Evaluate` than when I don't?

Comment: @JasonB The form with `Evaluate`, or `With[{mat = matrix}`, is putting the entire matrix inside the compiled function rather than referencing through an external call.

Comment: You can find this out using the `CompiledFunctionTools` package's function `CompilePrint`. Using `Evaluate`, you let `Compile` know what `matrix` is in advance; without `Evaluate`, the compiled function has to check the value of `matrix` with the Mathematica kernel each time it executes, and that's slow.